# RDP connection unstable, although ping is fine

Tags: windows-10, vpn, remote-desktop

I use VPN (PPTP) + Remote Desktop to connect to my work machine (both running Windows 10).

The remote desktop connection is not as stable as I would like it to be: Usually, everything is fine and responsive, but every 0.5-3 minutes the connection "hangs" for a few seconds, I get the "reconnecting" window, and after another second I can continue to work. The "Connection attempt" counter never exceeds 1.

[image: RDP reconnecting]

This is mildly annoying, so I am trying to find the reason for it. I tried pinging the RDP server from the RDP client with the following result:

```
C:\Users\Heinzi>ping -t <myHostName>

Pinging <myHostName> [<myIpAddress>] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=42ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=42ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Request timed out.
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=42ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Request timed out.
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=50ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=63ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=127
Reply from <myIpAddress>: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=127

Ping statistics for <myIpAddress>:
    Packets: Sent = 287, Received = 285, Lost = 2 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 19ms, Maximum = 63ms, Average = 26ms
```

Looks fine, doesn't it? (Yes, I did see the two "Request timed out" lines, but their timing does not coincide with the problems mentioned above.)

Since ping is fine, I conclude that the network connection is stable (enough). What else could be the reason for the RDP instabilities? What else can I do to find the source of the problem?

Comment: ...don't you hate it too if someone posts the exact same strange problem you have, but noone seems to have a solution... *sigh*